# Changing temporary from RAID to AHCI Windows

Tags: ahci

Recently I installed a Samsung 970 EVO plus NVMe M2 SSD in my Dell xps 9370. Everything went great, except for the fact that I had 600 Gb of unallocated spaces that I couldn't merge due to the fact that it was not adjacent to my C partition. I read that this could be fixed by using Gparted from a live USB and so I did. However Gparted couldn't find my NVMe SSD and after some research I found that the cause for this is because my SATA setting is set to RAID instead of AHCI. My question is if I could switch my SATA setting temporary to AHCI so I can boot from my live USB, fix my partitions with Gparted and then switch back to RAID without ruining my Windows 10 installation?

Comment: Do you have Intel RST installed?

Comment: @Ramhound how would this help me?

Answer (score -2):

Wait for other responses or perhaps someone more experienced may confirm what I am suggesting. I think doing all of these changes in safe mode is going to work best.

Type "msconfig" in run. Select the Boot Tab and choose safe boot. Reboot and enter bios during that reboot. Change to AHCI Mode and any other changes needed. Save and let the system boot into safe mode. Perform the changes needed. At this point you can probably reverse the "safe boot" in msconfig but if you want to be safe you can continue in safe mode. Reboot and enter bios. Set bios back to RAID and any other changes. Save and allow to reboot. If you opted to stay in safe mode to this point go ahead and disable it in msconfig and then reboot.

There are other ways to get into safemode obviously but this way keeps it active until you are ready without having to choose safe mode each boot.

Hope this helps.  NOTE !!!  I am not sure about editing the partition. I believe it is possible to edit a partition without losing data. What I outlined above is mainly to prevent an issue during the switch between ACHI and Raid.